# UK Districts Not Mapping Power BI

Tags: mapping, powerbi, gis

Folks, my issue should be simple.

I am trying to map UK districts in Kent. But when I try to map the district of `Medway` I get the following;

[image: tached:]

This is obviously a polygon for all of `Kent`. My question is what alias do I need for `Medway` to get it to map correctly. When you turn on the rest of the districts there is no issue at all. but as you can see `Medway` is missing.

[image]

I have tried the following iterations;

`Medway Towns`

`Medway UA`

`Medway Unitary Authority`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally I would have expected it to work fine. In this particular visualization, Power BI integrates with Bing, so that seems to be messing it up. You can try typing "Medway Kent", the results seem to be better. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered you can cheese it, but selecting one of the Medway towns such as `Rochester`, `Gillingham`, `Chatham` or `Strood`. Is there a better solution? Now I am stuck with the issue of the hover-over saying `Rochester`